# what does CPU% means in `ps auxf` for processes with parent/child relationship?

Tags: linux, cpu, process, ps

When I use `ps auxf` to display process information with **ASCII art process hierarchy**. Processes with parent/child relation is listed as below.

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root       389  0.0  0.0  21476  1284 ?        Ss    2014   0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
root      6567  0.0  0.0  21472   840 ?        S     2014   0:00  \_ /sbin/udevd --daemon
root      6568  0.0  0.0  21472   840 ?        S     2014   0:00  \_ /sbin/udevd --daemon
```

I'm wondering how `ps` calculates the resources(CPU, mem) they're using, are they independent or is there a sum-total thing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends from the column of `ps` you have activated. If you see in `man ps` in the section **STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS** you will find first:

> %cpu  %CPU  cpu utilization of the process in "##.#" format.  Currently, it is the CPU time used divided by the time the process has been running (cputime/realtime ratio), expressed as a percentage.  It will not add up to 100% unless you are lucky.  (alias pcpu).

and **after**

> **cp CP**        per-mill (tenths of a percent) CPU usage.  (see %cpu).
>   **cputime**     TIME      **cumulative** CPU time, "[DD-]hh:mm:ss" format.  (alias time).

I underline that you will find again later the note:

> CPU usage is currently expressed as the percentage of time spent running during the entire lifetime of a process.  This is not ideal, and it does not conform to the standards that ps otherwise conforms to.  **CPU usage is unlikely to add up to exactly 100%**.

You can find interesting  **`S`** for what it concerns *zombies* wasted resources in the *OUTPUT MODIFIERS* section, and **mem** for memory usage:

> %mem        %MEM      ratio of the process's resident set size  to the physical memory on the machine, expressed as a percentage.  (alias pmem).